# NodeJS code not working

Tags: javascript, php, node.js

My nodeJS code isn't working for some reason. I'm new to nodeJS, so excuse my ignorance. 
Here's the server code:

```
var http = require('http');

console.log("before");
var app = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    console.log("Server Created");
}).listen(3000);

var io = require('socket.io').listen(app);

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
console.log("Client Connected");
});
```

Here is my client code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var socketio = io.connect("http://localhost:3000");

</script>
```

I run the server, then go to index.html which contains the client code. I feel like I must be missing something obvious :| Client Connected never prints.

Comment: Any errors in console?

Comment: No, there aren't errors

Comment: @Nonemoticoner I was working from a tutorial. Maybe in the client code, io isn't recognized? Not sure where that variable comes from.

Comment: You are loading the socket.io client-side library in index.html?

Comment: @gcampbell I would assume so :\ How do I ensure that?

Comment: Check for a `<script>` tag with `src="socketio.js"` or something like that.

Comment: @gcampbell Ah I guess I forgot. Do I set a script to be socketio.js? Or does google have a hosted api for that?

Comment: I edited server code, it runs fine. But doesn't log to the console "Server Created"

Comment: @Wyatt The [page on npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io) tells you to use it differently to how you've done it.

Answer (score 1):

looks like your server code is just fine.

Have you tried changing ***localhost*** to ***IP Address*** in your client code like the following:

```
   ...
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://<YOUR_IP>:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
       var socket = io('http://<YOUR_IP:3000');
   </script>
```